# Expl3: understand how new command using sequence processes arguments

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3, definition, sequence

I'm just getting started with `expl3`. I had a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688000/how-to-use-loop-for-creating-defined-number-of-newcommands-counting-authors) which initiated about automating the process of printing authors of a specific paper and their further informations.

The solution by Alan Munn works great. To use only the authors defined inside the commands I tried to create my own command to get the particular informations from the sequence and print them seperated by dashes (therefore, i kept the other variables out of the MWE and both commands, mentioned below, only print the authors. `\printauthormeta` would normally print additional informations).

If I use a simple new defined command `\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthornames}{}{\seq_use:Nn \l_dai_authors_seq {~--~}}` it works fine when i recall `\printauthornames`:

[image: correct arranged names]

But if i try to copy the workflow from the solution: first defining an new `expl3` command `\cs_new_protected:Nn \dai_map_author_names:nn` and afterwards use it in a `\NewDocumentCommand` (like the original author did for `\dai_map_author_info:nn`, see the MWE), the authors are printed multiple times:

[image: names printed too often]

Here is the full MWE with the working simple command commented out:

```latex
\documentclass[%
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% First define three sequences for storing the data
\seq_new:N \l_dai_authors_seq

% User command to enter authors (comma separated)
\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{m}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_dai_authors_seq {#1}
}

% command to print only authors seperated by dash's: not working
\cs_new_protected:Nn \dai_map_author_names:nn {
    {\seq_use:Nn \l_dai_authors_seq {~--~}}
}

% internal command to print an author/affiliations/email block
\cs_new_protected:Nn \dai_map_author_info:nn {
    {\parindent=0pt
        {\seq_item:Nn \l_dai_authors_seq {#1}\par}
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
    }
}
% User command to print all the author blocks which would include additional information in the full document
\NewDocumentCommand \printauthormeta {} {
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_dai_authors_seq \dai_map_author_info:nn
}
%\NewDocumentCommand{\printauthornames}{}{\seq_use:Nn \l_dai_authors_seq {~--~}}
\NewDocumentCommand \printauthornames {} {
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l_dai_authors_seq \dai_map_author_names:nn
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\authors{Margaret Atwood, Zadie Smith, Madeleine Thien}

\begin{document}

\section{Autoren}

\printauthormeta

\printauthornames

\end{document}
```

Since the simple solution with only `NewDocumentComman` works perfectly fine, I just want to understand what went wrong with my second mentioned try to first define an internal `expl3` command which then can be used in a "regular" Latex command. I guess it could have something to do with the arguments `:nn`. When they are nested inside multiple commands/definitions I still have problems recognizing how to use them.

Comment: you should read the definition of \seq_map_indexed:NN in the reference (interface3). It will call the function for every item in your sequence, this means `\dai_map_author_info:nn` is executed three times.

Comment: Hi @Ulrike, thanks. I read it. I understand the repetition progress now, i guess (Although, i don't fully understand what <item> stands for...). So it would be enough to just use `\NewDocumentCommand \printauthornames {} {\dai_map_author_names:nn}` or not?

Comment: Btw. Is there any advantage in using a `cs_new` command as intermediate step and then creating a `NewDocumentCommand` over just using the latter directly?

Comment: OK, sitting in the train on my way to work, I understand why it is necessary to define a `cs_new` command as intermediate step for the more complex code of the question mentioned at the top of the post. My bad :)