# How to measure height of expected output from \listoffigures

Tags: macros, table-of-contents, expl3, expansion

I [defined a new command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688992/automatic-columnbreak-in-multicol-env-if-section-content-is-short) `\sectiontest{<text part>}` to measure the height of a particular part of text in relation to the `\textheight`. If the height of the test part transcends half the textheight, it inserts a `\newcolumn` command to shift the following text to the next column, since it is used in a `multicol*` environment of an otherwise singlecolumned document. So far, it works fine with `blindtext` or even some other simple commands.

But now I tried to insert `\listoffigures` as argument to `\sectiontest{}` and it doesn't work.

Either the height of the `listoffigures` seems to be measured correctly, but the list itself isn't printed:

[image: Right measuring, no list printed]

Or, if i put an *expandafter* in front (`\sectiontest\expandafter{\listoffigures}`), the list itself is printed, but the measuring mechanism isn't working, since there is no `\newcolumn` inserted, as it should be the case, if the measured section transcends half the `\textheight`:

[image: list printed but no measuring]

I guess it has to do with the nested structure of my own commands, since there is a `\testheight` command – which does the actual measuring – inside the `\sectiontest` command. And they aren't expanded in the right way if a command like `\listoffigures` that needs more than one compilation run is used as argument.

I also tried a `expl3` solution (which I generally would prefer) to get it right using `\exp_args:Nc/x/...` in combination with `\cs_new:Nn/...` together with `\listoffigures` commands, but had no success.

Expansion still is the most obscure part of Latex syntax to me – be it `expl3` (which is a *little bit* clearer to me) or `source2e`.

Maybe someone else has a clue, how to get it working. This would be great.

Here is my MWE, with a whole bunch of test pictures to get a long lof ;)

```latex
\documentclass[%
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{noto}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% tests if the height of the text part tested is bigger or smaller than textheight
\NewDocumentCommand{\columntest}{}{%
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\int_to_arabic:n {\metaheight}} < {\int_to_arabic:n {\textheight/2}} {} {\newcolumn}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\sectiontest}{m}{%
    \testheight{#1}\par
    \columntest
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% command for measuring the height of a text part. The text part is the argument of the command
\newlength{\metaheight}
\newcommand{\testheight}[1]{%
    \settoheight{\metaheight}{%
        \parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\noindent#1}}%
    #1\par%
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
        \clearpage
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
        \sectiontest\expandafter{\listoffigures}
        \blindtext[3]
    \end{multicols*}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Maybe my approach to measure the height of a text part like `\listoffigures` or anything similar is completely wrong. Thus, I'm also open for completely different ideas how to accomplish my goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out using the `l3fp` package of LaTeX3. Its an easy compare function which takes the `\pagetotal` height and compares it with half the `\textheight` (in my case slightly over half the `textheight` for layout reasons.

It gives me the expected output to insert an automatic `\newcolumn` if the part above the command crosses the middle of the page:

[image: Without newcolumn]

[image: With newcolumn]

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass[%
]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\columnheighttest}{}{
    \fp_compare:nNnTF {\pagetotal} > {\textheight/2.1} {\newcolumn} {}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{atbegshi,picture} %line at middle pf the page
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \put(0,\dimexpr-\topmargin-1in %
        -\headheight-\headsep
        -.5\textheight\relax){%
            \line(1,0){\paperwidth}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext

    \clearpage
    \begin{multicols*}{2}
        \listoffigures
        
        \columnheighttest
        
        \blindtext[3]
    \end{multicols*}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{Ziel ist es, innerafrikanische Beziehungen und Vernetzungen der letzten 6.000 Jahre}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```